# Merge several data frames named inside a vector

Tags: r

I am trying to merge some data frames, precisely 4, but I would like my command to work with whichever amount of them. Those data frames are named in a vector:

```
dataframes<-c('df1', 'data2', 'd3', 'samples4')
```

All data frames present the same data, but they belong to different samples. As an example, the first dataframe is as following:

```
ID  count1

A     0
B     67
C     200
D     12
E     0
```

My desired output would contain a column with the counts of each ID for each sample:

```
ID  count1  count2 count3  count4

A     0       2       0     30
B     67     100     300    500
C     200     2      1025   0
D     12      4       0     10
E     0       0       20    2
```

I have tried the following commands:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="ID"), list(unname(get(dataframes))))
```

```
as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, unname(get(dataframes))))
```

But in both cases I get just the first data frame. No merging is occuring.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What are the exact errors? "No one has worked" does not provide enough detail to troubleshoot.

Comment: What is the structure of those data frames? What type of merge do you want to do? (columns, rows)

Comment: @matt_jay  I've added this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), count = c(2,45,24,21))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), count = c(11,35,4,2))
```

I'd suggest to just add a column with the sample name to each dataframe, e.g.:

```
df1["sample"] <- "sample1"
df2["sample"] <- "sample2"
```

Then merge them "vertically" by using something like `rbind()`.

```
all_data <- rbind(df1, df2)  # this can take more dataframes
```

This "long format" should also make it easier to filter rows by sample.

If you still need to have the wider structure you describe above (with a column for each sample), you can use [reshape2::dcast()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/reshape2/versions/1.4.4/topics/cast) to construct it:

```
library(reshape2)
all_data <– dcast(all_data, ID ~ sample, value.var="count")
```

Result:

```
  ID sample1 sample2
1  A       2      11
2  B      45      35
3  C      24       4
4  D      21       2
```